# Using MySQL C++ connector connection refused

Tags: c++, mysql-connector, mysql

I get this error when connecting to a MySQL database:

```
Connection using old (pre-4.1.1) authentication protocol refused (client option 'secure_auth' enabled)
```

The problem seems to occur by using different versions of libmysql.dll.

I could connect using a previous version which I got from installing MySQL Community Server (5.6.0). However, when I built the libmysql.lib and .dll myself, using the MySQL C/connector source code, the connection fails with the above error. So this leads me to think that there might be a setting within the source code when building the DLL file that I must observe to connect properly. What might it be?

Comment: What's your running db server version? Is it the one you mention in your question, or did you install that one just to get the connector source?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not a connector issue, but rather a database one: this [blog post](http://mysqlblog.fivefarmers.com/2012/05/30/why-your-pre-4-1-client-wont-like-mysql-5-6/) covers it. Basically, the password hashing changed from 4.1 onward, but the old method was kept around with the `OLD_PASSWORD` function to access it. However, version 5.6 decided to simply refuse connections still based on that authentication method.

So you have 2 solutions:

1. As a first step, follow the quick and dirty work around hinted by the mysql documentation, by using the server [--skip-secure-auth](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_secure-auth) startup parameter: this is a short term solution to get your db connections working again after upgrading the server
2. upgrade your database content, by having all account passwords using the old encryption method updated to the new one: This is the prefered method, since you will effectively be using the new encryption, and avoid the insecure situation that the above switch still allows. *Don't forget to remove the switch* from the first solution once your db is up to date.